# Normal to a tangent plane as a function of a and b

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I have determined a tangent plane to be
$$z = a(-b+y) + x(b-1)$$
$$ab = x(b-1) + ay - z$$
At the point (a,b)

I want to determine the normal to this plane as a function of a and b. I am not entirely sure as to what this means "As a function of a and b".

So I assume I will find the normal using the dot product of plane to normal = 0.
$$(b-1, a,-1) * (\zeta,\beta,\gamma) = 0$$
$$\zeta(b-1) + \beta*a - \gamma = 0$$
$$-\frac{\zeta(b-1) + \gamma,}\beta = a$$
$$\frac{a\beta - \gamma,}\zeta + 1 = b$$

I am not sure if this is what is wanted, or if there is a better way to solve this. If anyone can shed some light, that would be appreciated. This is from a past exam 2012S2 UQ, for course 'Multivariate Calculus and Ordinary Differential Equations'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of your plane can be written in the form
$$
(x,y,z) \cdot ( b-1, a, -1) = ab
$$
From this, you can see (I expect) that the plane normal is in the direction
of the vector $( b-1, a, -1)$.

Geometrically, the equation says that every point of the plane has the same projection onto the vector $( b-1, a, -1)$, and this can only be the case if the vector $( b-1, a, -1)$ is normal to the plane.